# js script displaying only true booleans from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Name, 
Quantity, 
Price, 
Option1 (bool), 
Option2 (bool)
```

that I'm displaying on a simple webpage using php, js, and jquery. Although the script works, I'm trying to find a way to display the non-bool (Name, Quantity, and Price) and true-bool values only. This is the working js script:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 done();
});

function done() {
      setTimeout( function() { 
      updates(); 
      done();
      }, 200);
}

function updates() {
     $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
         $("ul").empty();
     $.each(data.result, function(){
         $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li><li>Quantity: " + this['quantity']+"</li><li>Price: "+this['price']+"</li><li>Option1: "+this['option1']+"</li><li>Option2: "+this['option2']+"</li><br />");
     });  
});
```

Since I have almost no js experience, any help will be highly appreciated!

Here's my fetch.php script for your reference:

```
<?php

include_once('db.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$result = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )

    array_push($result, array(
                        'name' => $row[0]));
                        'quantity' => $row[1],
                        'price'  => $row[2],
                        'option1'  => $row[3],
                        'option2' => $row[4]));


echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));

?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function updates() {
 $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
     $("ul").empty();
 $.each(data.result, function(){

     $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li><li>Quantity: " + this['quantity']+"</li><li>Price: "+this['price']+"</li>";

if (this['option1']) {
    $("ul").append("<li>Option1: "+this['option1']+"</li>");
 }
if (this['option2']) {
     $("ul").append("<li>Option2: "+this['option2']+"</li><br />");
  }     
     });  
   });
```